# How to find a object and insert it in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m trying to pick up the shop_id and subscription_id from a cart and insert/save them into the purchase database.

I have a cart, line_items and subscriptions.

And this is how I’m trying to do this:

```
@purchase = @cart.line_items.build 
@purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)
@purchase.save!
```

I got the shop_id, but the subscription_id for some reason is nil.

Any ideas what maybe wrong?

**Update 1**

```
def purchase_params
  params.permit(:subscription_id, :shop_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :id, :cart_id)
end


Started POST "/line_items?subscription_id=1" for ::1 at 2017-06-18 16:45:12 +0300
Processing by LineItemsController#create as HTML
Parameters:  {"authenticity_token"=>"dUonc4AnCvFTuK1b+TAKho/kmpvl7XaOM7SGcNalzdQV1+CqhY4 p7znDiL/TV12pVKeDTqlR7j5NL65X1S/75A==", "subscription_id"=>"1"}
Cart Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" =   ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2017-06-18 13:45:12 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-18 13:45:12 UTC]]
 (0.7ms)  commit transaction
 Subscription Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "line_items" ("subscription_id", "cart_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["subscription_id", 1], ["cart_id", 18], ["created_at", 2017-06-18 13:45:12 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-18 13:45:12 UTC]]
 (0.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/carts/18
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

I'm implementing braintree payments via the following create method and this is where I have the small peace of code:

```
def create
  current_shop.has_payment_info?
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: @cart.total_price,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
            customer: {
              first_name: current_shop.first_name,
              last_name: current_shop.last_name,
              company: current_shop.shop_name,
              email: current_shop.email,
              phone: current_shop.phone_number,
              website: current_shop.web_page
            },
            options: { store_in_vault: true })


      if @result.success?
    current_shop.update(braintree_customer_id:    @result.transaction.customer_details.id) unless  current_shop.has_payment_info?


    @purchase = @cart.line_items.build 
    @purchase.save!
    @purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)
    @purchase.save!
    @cart.destroy
    redirect_to front_index_path, notice: 'Your transaction was succesfully processed'
  else
gon.client_token = generate_client_token
redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!'
  end
end
```

**Update 2**

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shop
    belongs_to :cart
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :subscriptions
end


class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
    belongs_to :shop
end

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :purchases
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

Comment: Please update the question with `purchase_params` method and the related server log

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pavan. I just updated the question.

Comment: Can you also post the related models with associations?

Comment: I just did @Pavan, also I added a little description and method before update 2. So you can have a better idea on what I'm doing.

Comment: Try adding `@purchase.subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]` before `@purchase.save!`

Comment: Ok I delete `@purchase = @cart.line_items.id.find(session[:subscription_id])` and added this
 `@purchase.subscription_id = params[:subscription_id]` but the following error appears `undefined method subscription_id=' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Add that after `@purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)`

Comment: The same thing @Pavan, its inserting everything except the subscription_id `SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "purchases" ("shop_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["shop_id", 1], ["created_at", 2017-06-18 14:34:33 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-18 14:34:33 UTC]]`

Comment: Ok remove `subscription_id` from `purchase_params` and try changing this `@purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)` to `@purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params).merge(subscription_id: params[:subscription_id])`

Comment: hmmmm weird... now `I'm getting this undefined method merge for #<Purchase:0x007f9059819728>`

Comment: Sorry Try like this `@purchase = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params.merge(subscrip‌​tion_id: params[:subscription_id]))`

Comment: I'm getting this error : `unknown attribute subscrip‌‌​​tion_id for Purchase`

Comment: Ah, there it is! Do you have `subscription_id` in Purchase table?

Comment: yes I do `t.integer  "subscription_id"`

Comment: Not in the migration. Check in db in purchases table

Comment: how do i do that? rails db

Comment: Just go to the console with `rails c` and do `Purchase.column_names` and paste the result here

Comment: Yes its in there `=> ["id", "subscription_id", "shop_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "cart_id", "line_item_id"] `

Comment: ok it did go thru without an error... but still no subscription_id   `SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "purchases" ("shop_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["shop_id", 1], ["created_at", 2017-06-18 15:20:28 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-18 15:20:28 UTC]]`

Answer (score 0):

Build here only links up a new line_item with @cart, like this, LineItem.new(cart_id: @cart.id). subscription_id is not linked here as @cart doesn't have a relationship with subscriptions.

```
@cart.line_items.build 
line_item = @cart.line_items.build
```

fetch the desired subscription_id and assign it to 'line_item.subscription_id '

```
line_item.subscription_id = fetch_the_subscription_id
line_item.save!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ucpuzz... I added your code but this error appears now `undefined local variable or method subscription_id`..... weird because subscription_id is in line_items `LineItem.column_names
 => ["id", "subscription_id", "cart_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "purchase_id", "quantity"]`

Comment: @cart doesn't have subscription_id, you have to pass the subscription you want to link with the cart in line_tem table.   From your question it is not clear where you get the subscriptions, may be this is what you wanted, 'line_item.subscription_id = current_shop. subscriptions.first.id'

Comment: In the error u posted above it is complaining 'subscription_id'  on the right side of equal to, not the subscription_id  column.